# Contar numero de días entre 2 fechas según condición

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en mysql con estos 3 campos

- `fechainicio` (tipo date)
- `fechafin` (tipo date) y
- `actualmente` (varchar), que tiene los valores `S`(si)/`N`(no) esta laborando actualmente.

Lo que quiero hacer es un consulta que, si `Actualmente` es `N`, me cuente el tiempo entre las 2 fechas (días). Lo quiero hacer en SQL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que hayas intentado

Answer (score 2):

Puedes valerte de:

- la función [`datediff()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp) para obtener los días que hay entre dos fechas
- Una sentencia [`case`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) para aplicar esta función solamente cuando el valor del campo `actualmente` es `N`, o bien
- la función [`if`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php), con el mismo fin.

En el siguiente query utilizo ambas:

```
select   fechainicio
       , fechafin
       , actualmente
       , case actualmente
           when 'N' then datediff(fechafin, fechainicio)
         end dias
       , if(actualmente = 'N', datediff(fechafin, fechainicio), null) dias2
  from Empleado
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
fechainicio    fechafin       actualmente dias    dias2
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------
2017-01-01     (null)         S           (null)  (null)
2016-06-01     (null)         S           (null)  (null)
2014-11-01     2015-11-01     N           365     365
2017-01-01     2018-08-10     N           586     586
2019-08-15     (null)         S           (null)  (null)
2015-01-01     2017-12-31     N           1095    1095
2016-02-20     2017-02-20     N           366     366
2016-02-26     (null)         S           (null)  (null)
```

En lo personal, prefiero la sentencia `case`, primero por estar escrita en SQL estándar, la función `if` no existe en otros motores y en segundo lugar porque con la función `if` siempre se evalúa la expresión que se retornará en caso verdadero y falso, con el case, solamente en caso de cumplirse la condición.

He dejado un [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04b51/6/0) donde puedes probar la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(fechaFin, fechaInicio) AS dias FROM table WHERE actualmente = 'N';
```

Comment: Si bien la respuesta puede proporcionar el resultado deseado por quien hace la pregunta, deberías de explicar el funcionamiento de la misma, pues sino probablemente quede como cerrada.

Comment: Es que me parece que este caso es bastante simple y claro. Por ejemplo la otra respuesta hace mucho más de lo que pidió el OP y me parece que solo complica las cosas. 
Pero bueno, si te parece que es mejor cerrar esta, no hay problema.